# Input of mathematical functions such as, cosine tangent logarithm in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to make a small Mathematical app in Android, but I am finding a little problem. 
My problem is this, I would like my app to be able to correctly interpret the contents of the EditText, so that it is able to take as input not only numbers but also mathematical munctions xuch as sine cosine tangent logarithm etc.. I'm not an expert programmer, and I never found this type of problem before.

Comment: What exactly you want the user to input in the `EditText`? example : `sin 30` ?

Comment: I want that the EditText, are also able to interpret the input of mathematical functions such as sin30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try a java formel parser.
There are a bunch of them for java. For example: http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_java/index.html

That could than look like this:

```
Parser prs = new Parser();
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String expr = et.getText().toString();
String result = prs.parse(expr);
```

To install it you have to download: 
http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_java/html/files/expression_parser_java.zip

And then you have to copy the java files into your source folder in eclipse.

Did you do that this way?
If so could you post the exception.

Comment: for use these lines of code that you're suggesting, I have to import some particular library? because the code gives me error right here: Parser prs = new Parser();

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
EditText et = (EditText)additem.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String item = et.getText().toString();
String splitter[] = item.split("\\d+");
if(splitter[0].equals("sin"))
   // perform sine
//similarly for other functions
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a parser.

You can either follow frugi's advice and use a java library, or you could implement your own.

A simple parser to implement and that is suitable for this problem is the [Shunting Yard algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Pros with implementing your own parser:

- Much more control over the grammar and expressions.
- Good experience.
- Fun.

Cons:

- Takes more time to get ready (obviously) than a 3rd party library.
- Could be buggy.

I would recommend writing your own!

Comment: I'm trying to use the Frugi's advice, I hope to be able to apply it to my needs